# How to make SwipeRefreshLayout refresh on demand?

Tags: android, layout

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout of some open source project (CySmart).

I want to add a button which would refresh the layout as if it was swiped down as it is now (On demand).

How can this effect be achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final SwipeRefreshLayout layout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_refresh);

    layout.setOnRefreshListener(refreshListener);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dispatchRefresh(); //Refresh
        }
    });
}
private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener refreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        dispachRefresh();
    }
};

private void dispatchRefresh(){

    layout.setRefreshing(true);
    //code to refesh data, etc.
}
```

And then;

```
layout.setRefreshing(false);
```

when refreshing is complete

Comment: This does display the refreshing animation. but the onRefresh event of the swiperefreshlayout isn't called...

Comment: No it doesn't, but how I see myself implementing this is by having another method called `dispatchRefresh` and calling it when both the button is clicked and when `onRefresh` is triggered. So that inside that method i do `layout.setRefreshing(true);` and start the actual refresh...

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you edited the answer..I will try this